# Spring Boot - Set Alias name for email address

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail using Spring Boot. I am able to send the mail successfully but in the mailbox, I am seeing the alias name along with the from email address like `Customer Desk[customercare@xyz.com]`. I only want the from address alias name to be displayed in the mailbox like `CustomerDesk`. Below is my implementation of the same.

```
public class MailHandlerImpl implements MailHandler {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendEmail() {
        String emailToAddress = "abc@xyz.com"
        String emailFromAddress = "Customer Desk <customercare@xyz.com>"
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

        try {

            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFromAddress));
            messageHelper.setTo(InternetAddress.parse(emailToAddress));
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how I can only display the Alias name in the mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with `JavaMailSender`. However, I think passing alias name like following should do the trick,

```
mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("customercare@xyz.com", "Customer Desk"));
```

Comment: I did try the above snippet, but I am still able to see the email address next to the alias name. Seems like it didn't work.

Comment: I haven't used Spring for a while. Can you check if following works for you? message.setFrom("customercare@xyz.com", "Customer Desk")

Comment: Yes, I tried the above, still it is showing the email address. Is it something to do with the format of my input from email address? Appreciate you providing your suggestions though!

Comment: I don't know how to do it with Spring, but you need to be able to set the message headers independently of the addresses you're going to send the message to.  JavaMail lets you do this because the Transport.send method accepts addresses that might not be the same as what's in the headers.